# Exception while trying to execute Alter keyspace in cql

Tags: exception, cassandra, cql, alter

I am new to cassandra. I have created a keyspace as the following

```
    CREATE KEYSPACE sample WITH replication = {
      'class': 'SimpleStrategy',
      'replication_factor': '1'
    };
```

Now i want the properties of the keyspace to be altered so i execute the statement

```
    alter keyspace sample with placement_strategy='org.apache.cassandra.locator.NetworkTopologyStrategy' AND stratey_options={DC1:1,DC2:0};
```

But i get the below error while trying to execute the statement

```
Bad Request: Failed parsing statement: [alter keyspace "sample" with placement_strategy='org.apache.cassandra.locator.NetworkTopologyStrategy' AND strategy_options={DC1:1,DCC2:0};] reason: NullPointerException null
```

Can someone please tell me the reason behind the error and the proper alter keyspace statement to make the changes to its properties?

Comment: version of cassandra?

Comment: @kkmishra: cassandra 1.2.16

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Cassandra-2.0.x then the following alter command will work for you.

```
ALTER KEYSPACE sample WITH REPLICATION =  { 'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'DC1' : 1, 'DC2' : 0 }
```

I think it will work for Cassandra-1.2.16 as well.

Comment: ookay but for 1.2.16?

Comment: It will work for 1.2.16 as well, please try and let me know if there is any problem.